# SUP error while sending date parameter to server

Tags: ios, objective-c, sup, smp

I am developing an iOS app using Sybase Unwired Platform 2.1.3 I am getting error while sending `date` parameter to database.

Here is my code,

```
@try 
{
    SUP105Sales_order *insertRow =[[SUP105Sales_order alloc]init];
    int32_t idValue =2671;
    int32_t custID =103;
    int32_t sales =506;

    insertRow.id_=idValue;
    insertRow.cust_id=custID;
    insertRow.order_date=[NSDate date];
    insertRow.fin_code_id=@"r1";
    insertRow.region=@"Hyd";
    insertRow.sales_rep=sales;

    [insertRow save];
    [insertRow submitPending];
    [SUP105SUP105DB synchronize];
}
@catch (NSException *exception) {
   NSLog(@"Exception---%@",exception.description);
}
```

Server log,

```
2014-02-28 16:39:41.833 WARN Other Thread-182 [SUP105.server.SUP105DB]{"_op":"C","level":5,"code":412,"eisCode":"257","message":"com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.SybSQLException:SQL Anywhere Error -157: Cannot convert '' to a timestamp","component":"Sales_order","entityKey":"3210004","operation":"create","requestId":"3210005","timestamp":"2014-02-28 11:09:41.646","messageId":0,"_rc":0}
```

I think the error above is due to date format. I have tried few other ways to send date to the Sup server, but it did not work.

How to send `DATE` format to the `sales_order` table to the `order_date` column  from iOS native app?

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

The sybase doc says [here](http://infocenter.sybase.com/archive/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc36584.1260/html/iqerror/Errsybcode.htm)

> You cannot insert data into a timestamp column. You must either insert an explicit null by typing “NULL” in the column or use an implicit null by providing a column list that skips the timestamp column. Adaptive Server updates the timestamp value after each insert or update. See “Inserting data into specific columns” for more information.

In your case it seems that the value sent by your app is an empty string "" which is not allowed for a timestamp field. You can either skip the column in your insert request or set it to "NULL".

Could you try one those options.

Comment: I have tried What you said ..but there is no result..i think im not sending the Correct Date format  to Date datatype in sales_order table.